# Polynomial systems and algebraic functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, computer-algebra, enumerative-combinatorics

An algebraic function $y(x)$ is defined as the solution of a polynomial equation of the form $p(x,y)=0$, that is one making the identity $p(x,y(x))=0$ true --- in either analytical or formal power series sense, in any field --- for $p$ a *single* nonzero polynomial.

It seems to be folklore that one could equivalently consider *systems* of polynomial equations, $$p_1(x,y_1,...,y_n)=0,...,p_n(x,y_1,....,y_n)=0$$
defining tuples of functions $y_1(x),...,y_n(x)$. That is, the class of functions defined in this way would be the same.  Elimination theory, in the sense of algebraic geometry, is sometimes invoked in this respect: see e.g. http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSe01.pdf, p. 9:

[image]

Yet, the evidence of this fact is not so compelling to me, as it seems to imply that one can always eliminate $n-1$ of the $y_i$ variables in the system above.

**Question**: can anyone provide a precise reference to this fact, or a simple direct proof of it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Beyond implying that one can eliminate variables, it explicitly says that. I’m not sure if I understand the concern.

Comment: @ZachTeitler. The elimination ideal might be $\{0\}$.

Comment: Is Theorem 8.7 in the reference you’ve provided not exactly what you want? In that theorem, the elimination ideal can’t be zero.

Comment: @tim Oh, I see. So one should require that the system in question be zero-dimensional, when the $p_i$ s are considered as polynomials in $\mathbb{C}(x)[y_1,...,y_n]$. There is another aspect of this proof that puzzles me, though: it seems to me that one should consider the *radical* of $I=<h_1,...,h_s>$, rather than just $I$. Indeed, one wants the polynomials in $K[y_1]$ that vanish on $\Pi_1(V(h_1,...,h_s))$: isn't this an elimination ideal of $\sqrt{I}$?

Comment: @Michele I believe you are right. Finding the elimination ideal of $I$, instead of $\sqrt{I}$, means finding a solution $y_1(x)$ that is constrained by some "extra conditions", for example, that $y_1(x)$ might not only vanish at some points, but also certain derivatives might vanish. Nevertheless, it is still true that–with some hypothesis such as the ideal $I$ being zero-dimensional–if $(y_1(x),\dotsc,y_n(x))$ is a solution of the system, then each $y_i(x)$ is a solution of a single equation, $p_i(x,y_i)$, obtained by elimination, and so each $y_i$ is an algebraic function.

Comment: I think I found a partial answer to this question in Kuich ans Salomaa's book *Semirings, Automata, Languages*, Ch. 15, Corollary 16.11 p. 352. They use elimination theory, more precisely resultant theory, to show the wanted statement, when the field is $\mathbb{Q}$ (rationals) and the system has a specific form.